# javafx printing a table with header and footer

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, tableview, javafx-8

I want to print tableview with header and footer but i hadn't found any code in javafx to print a table with header and footer so please if any one knows how to print a table so please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain your question as the data you have provided is insufficient !

Comment: i am just searching a code to print a table in javafx

Comment: `Table` in javafx is extends from the `Node` family. So you can directly print it

Comment: but i don't codes to print a table with printer in a A4 sheet

Comment: if you want to print a table on an a4 sheet then please follow [this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-example-javafx-8) !

Comment: but i cant add header in it

Comment: Why don't you use a custom layout, like a `VBox`. Add header(Label), Table and Footer to it and print the VBox ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BorderPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) with the Table as Center element and the header and footer element as Top and Bottom element, respectively.

Super simple example application:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            TableView table = new TableView();
            //Do stuff with your table...
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setTop(new Label("Awesome header text.")); //Set header
            root.setCenter(table); //add your table
            root.setBottom(new Label("Even more awesome footer text.")); //Set footer
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you literally want to print it on a sheet of paper, follow the [link already provided by ItachiUchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122228/javafx-printing-a-table-with-header-and-footer#comment39122281_25122228).

Comment: but the problem comes when i got the output i am explaining you with a example let i have 200 rows i can view only 50 row an rest is under scroll but when i print i got only 50 rows and rest 150 rows below scroll doesn't print

Comment: Okay, I understand your question now, but unfortunately I don't know of a (easy) solution, as JavaFX does not provide any way to set a header/footer for printing ([PrinterJob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html) and [Printer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/Printer.html)). 

You could file a JIRA for this.